# DisplayAlert con Entry

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hay alguna posibilidad de obtener un DisplayAlert con un Entry en su interior para recoger datos sin utilizar NuGet? Algo asi...

[image: DisplayAlert]

Answer (score 0):

La única manera de hacerlo sin usar librerías es que crees un control visual que este por encima, pero este oculto.

Pones un Grid que ocupe toda la pantalla, en su interior pones otro Grid, que también ocupe todo, con un fondo negro y una opacidad del 0,5 o así, para que haga el efecto del oscurecimiento, y bloquee la interfaz inferior, y en el centro pones tu control con lo que tu quieras.

Por defecto pones que este invisible, y cuando necesites usarlo lo pones visible. El botón cancelar lo limpia y lo oculta de nuevo, el aceptar lo mismo pero procesa los datos.

Igual es una tontería, pero recuerda que para que algo este por "encima" de otro algo, tiene que estar mas abajo en el xaml.

Comment: Podría hacerlo con DependencyService en cada plataforma ????

Comment: Podrías, pero yo lo estuve valorando y lo descarte, al final era mejor usar una librería, en vez de eso.

Comment: Cuál fue el motivo concreto para haberlo descartado????

Comment: En lo que yo estuve viendo, para android requería mucha mas implementación que la opción que te he puesto yo.

Comment: Entiendo que te refieres a que ponga una máscara que visualizo cuando corresponda. El problema es que no entiendo muy bien cómo poner el grid por encima y que aparezca cuando quiero yo.

Comment: Al final lo logré implementando Acr.UserDialogs .No me gusta mucho tener que utilizar vitaminas la verdad.